# Calculate the difference between results of two count(*) queries based on 2 tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate the difference between the results of 2 `count(*)`-type SELECT queries executed on 2 separate tables of my PostgreSQL database.

This what I'm currently using (however I should be able to wrap it all up into a single SELECT statement):

```
SELECT "count"(*) AS val1 FROM tab1;
SELECT "count"(*) AS val2 FROM tab2;
SELECT val2-val1;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A simple solution is select (count(CITY)-count(distinct(CITY))) from STATION;

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select 
  (
    SELECT 
      "count"(*) as val1 
    from 
      tab1
  ) - (
    SELECT 
      "count"(*) as val2 
    from 
      tab2
  ) as total_count
```

Answer (score 16):

for same table you can do this.

`select (count(abc)-count(DISTINCT xyz)) from tab;`

Comment: OP is asking for answer for different tables.

Answer (score 10):

```
select t1.cnt - t2.cnt
from (select count(*) as cnt from tab1) as t1
  cross join (select count(*) as cnt from tab2) as t2
```

Comment: Does anybody know how to execute this in Redshift? the code above is not supported: [0A000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet; java.lang.RuntimeException: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet;

Answer (score 6):

You can write many query to answer this question like:
As I am considering the question as we have table named as STATION and we have to now finding the difference between the total number of CITY entries in the table and the number of distinct CITY entries in the table

Query 1:

```sql
select (count(city)-count(distinct city)) from station;
```

Query 2:

```sql
select ((select count(city) as ans1 from station)-(select count(distinct city)
       as ans2 from station));
```

Query 3:

```sql
select (( select count(city) from station )-( select count(distinct city) from station ))
       as ans;
```

All the above mentioned query will work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(val) AS result
FROM (SELECT count(*) AS val FROM tab2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT -count(*) FROM tab1) sub;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4d49883568a150c2982e8ffefd003db7)**