# query to get the difference between total number of rows and distinct rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm new to SQL, wasn't able to write the correct SQL.
Given a table STATION that holds data for five fields namely ID, CITY, STATE, NORTHERN LATITUDE and WESTERN LONGITUDE.

```
+-------------+------------+
| Field       |   Type     |
+-------------+------------+
| ID          | INTEGER    |
| CITY        | VARCHAR(21)|
| STATE       | VARCHAR(2) |
| LAT_N       | NUMERIC    |
| LONG_W      | NUMERIC    |
+-------------+------------+
```

Let `NUM` be the number of cities and `NUMunique` be the number of unique cities, then write a query to print the value of `NUM` - `NUMunique`.

I tried:

```
select (count(CITY)- distinct count(CITY)) from STATION;
```

Comment: Yes i did, something like this, select (count(CITY)- distinct count(CITY)) from STATION;

Comment: I've edited your attempt into your post. I hope this way you can avoid downvotes. I suggest you edit your post further, to show what you got after your attempt. Regards and good luck!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: This is a question on Hacker Rank :P

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-4
thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 75):

You can use the select distinct inside the count and
try this way

```
select  (count(CITY)- count(distinct CITY)) from STATION;
```

Comment: lol I tried both querry structures listed here before I found this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701094/calculate-the-difference-between-results-of-two-count-queries-based-on-2-tabl/21701121 I'm trying to learn not to make things so hard.

Comment: i don't understand you comment  ..  try explain better .. the answer  you have found is for calculated  difference between cout form different table  .. this is for calculate difference  in the same table... let me know what you need ..

Comment: Why would you add the parentheses? I think there is no need.

Comment: @jdhao Correct  ..  .. the parentheses  are not needed ..

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) FROM STATION
```

Answer (score 5):

You can write many query to answer this question like:
As I am considering the question as we have table named as STATION and we have to now finding the difference between the total number of CITY entries in the table and the number of distinct CITY entries in the table

Query 1:

```sql
select (count(city)-count(distinct city)) from station;
```

Query 2:

```sql
select ((select count(city) as ans1 from station)-(select count(distinct city)
       as ans2 from station));
```

Query 3:

```sql
select (( select count(city) from station )-( select count(distinct city) from station ))
       as ans;
```

All the above mentioned queries will work.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server:-

```
    SELECT ABS((SELECT COUNT(CITY) FROM STATION)-(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) FROM STATION)) AS diff_num
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of calling ABS() ? Total count is always >= to DISTINT count. It will always be positive. Seems to be a redundant processing call.