# Oracle PL/SQL: count(*) between 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Trying counting the difference of count between 2 tables.

Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701094/calculate-the-difference-between-results-of-two-count-queries-based-on-2-tabl) answer but getting `00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"`

```
SELECT ( SELECT count(*) FROM XE_ERR_OVLP WHERE FLAG = 'E') 
- (SELECT count(*) FROM XE_ERR_RANG WHERE FLAG = 'H' ) as cnt;
```

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Add `from dual` at the end.

Comment: Thanks !. Work, up voted

Answer (score 7):

That is:

```
SELECT ( SELECT count(*) FROM XE_ERR_OVLP WHERE FLAG = 'E') 
  - (SELECT count(*) FROM XE_ERR_RANG WHERE FLAG = 'H' ) as cnt 
  from dual;
```

As opposed to other databases, Oracle requires a `from` clause. You can use the dummy table `dual` for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `FROM DUAL`
Your query should look like this

```
SELECT ( SELECT count(*) FROM XE_ERR_OVLP WHERE FLAG = 'E') 
- (SELECT count(*) FROM XE_ERR_RANG WHERE FLAG = 'H' ) as cnt
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UNION ALL` and `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(c) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT 1 AS c FROM XE_ERR_OVLP WHERE FLAG = 'E'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT -1 FROM XE_ERR_RANG WHERE FLAG = 'H') sub;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use **SUM** only **to calculate count difference** as follows.

```
select ( ( select sum(1) XE_ERR_OVLP WHERE FLAG = 'E' ) 
       - ( select sum(1) XE_ERR_RANG WHERE FLAG = 'H' ) 
    ) cnt from dual;
```